# What are some synonyms for 'the extent to which'?

Tags: idioms, synonyms

What are some synonyms for 'the extent to which'?

E.g. I want to say:

> The extent to which electoral fraud occurred will affect the
>   validity of the result.

But having used 'the extent to which' about a dozen times in my essay it would be good if there were some alternatives I can use. However, apart from 'the degree to which' I can't think of any similar expressions.

Comment: The level of electoral fraud that occurred...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rephrasing your statement and, in the process, making it even more clear. Perhaps this would work:

> Evidence of electoral fraud will call into question the validity of the result.

I basically replaced "The extent to which ... occurred" with "Evidence of ..."

Also, I replaced *affect* with *call into question* because something is either valid, or it is not. There is no degree to validity. The extent of electoral fraud won't make the result *less* valid. Rather, it will make it more likely that the question will arise of whether to invalidate the result.